# Multiline WPF ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` that I need to populate with some text data.

Currently my `ListViewItem` look this way (2 columns):

```
Name     Number of files    Files finished
```

XAML:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>


    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Here i have all my `GridViewColumnHeader` and my `Binding` data for example `Name` property:

```
<!-- file name column -->
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="File name" />
          <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                   </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
<GridViewColumn>
```

What i want to do now is to see my `Name` in first line and `NumberOfFiles` and `FilesFinished` in second line:

So after quick search i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101761/multiline-text-in-wpf-listview) solution.

So i add this:

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Grid>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition />
                          <ColumnDefinition />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <StackPanel>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />                                                                  
                 </StackPanel>
                 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberOfFiles}" />
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilesFinished}" />
                 </StackPanel>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

So after add my files into my `ListView` i cannot see any file, so i try to remove my `ListView.View` and still the files missing.

What i dong wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look fine. I just add listview name.

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="ListViewFiles">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Authors">
                <GridViewColumn Header="File name" Width="120" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="NumberOfFiles" Width="120" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberOfFiles}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Code Sample. Maybe you forget ListViewFiles.ItemsSource = items;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<File> items = new List<File>();
        items.Add(new File() { Name = "File One", NumberOfFiles = 2, Filesfished = "Yes" });
        items.Add(new File() { Name = "File Two", NumberOfFiles = 2, Filesfished = "No" });
        ListViewFiles.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    public class File
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfFiles { get; set; }

        public string Filesfished { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: But what about my other 2 properties? i can only see the Name